Nginx. Sub filter
Как в nginx, используя sub_filter на проксируемом сайте в конец каждой ссылки в a теге добавить косую черту? Используя регулярные выражения ничего не вышло, даже ставил модуль subs_filter.

Лучше исправить эти ссылки там где они создаются. Nginx ничего не знает про html, для него это просто текст, а парсить хоть сколько-нибудь сложных html регулярками это провальная идея.
